# Can we write the html5 code for playing video in php code?

Tags: php, html

My path of the video is stored in a php variable and i want to write the html5 code in php but it's showing error. Can you please tell me how to write the html5 code in php. I recently started using php so i am right now a beginner. My code is:

```
<video width="400" height="300" controls> 
    <source src="$link" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Comment: `<source src="<?=$link; ?>" type='video/mp4' />` or `<source src="<?php echo $link; ?>" type='video/mp4' />`

Comment: Better way is `<source src="<?php echo $link; ?>" type='video/mp4' />` (as writed by cmorrissey), because short tags can be disabled on server

Answer (score 0):

```
 <video width="400" height="300" controls> 
<source src="<?php echo $link;?>" type='video/mp4' /> 
</video>
```

I am not using short tags because in some severs are turn off.